# What is the significance of the provided code in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby. What I understood from below code that a New class MyClass is created with in the ABC module. What #1 to #4 is doing. Is this throwing different exceptions which is a subtype of CommonError?

```
class ABC::MyClass

  class AException < CommonError; end   #1
  class BException < CommonError; end   #2
  class CFailure < CommonError; end     #3
  class DException < CommonError; end   #4

  include ABC::Something

  # ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

end 

class CommonError < Exception
end
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Exception.html): _"A good practice is for a library to create a single “generic” exception class (typically a subclass of StandardError or RuntimeError) and have its other exception classes derive from that class. This allows the user to rescue the generic exception, thus catching all exceptions the library may raise even if future versions of the library add new exception subclasses."_

Comment: ... two complaints though: unless there are good reasons to do otherwise, `CommonError` should inherit from `StandardError` and it should also be nested under `ABC` to avoid name collisions.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]", its linked pages, and "[How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/)"

Answer (score 4):

That's just defining specific exceptions that can, presumably, be used within the code somewhere else, as in:

```
raise AException, "Something went wrong!"
```

This means you can `rescue` those later:

```
begin
  do_stuff!
rescue AException => e
  puts "Uh oh, AException went off! Those are super bad!"
  puts e # The message supplied in the raise call
end
```

The reason for `CommonError` is to act as a base-class for all these other exceptions. The argument to `rescue` is actually not a specific class, but a class *and all subclasses*, so if you `rescue CommonError` you get to capture all of these and potentially others defined elsewhere.